# Add Igraph to Visual Studio 2010 C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, igraph

I want to run a test example of `igraph` in VS 2010 C++. After downloading/extracting igraph code for Microsoft Visual Studio, I launched `igraph.sln` which created a bunch of files in that folder.

[image]

Now, I opened a new project and located test example of igraph. However, I have error that it cannot open "igraph.h" file.

[image]

How to add igraph library to C++ project properly for a new project?

**EDIT:** 
After adding additional include directories that point to *include* folder of `igraph` errors got resolved. However, after building the project I get the following errors.

[image]

After [googling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17771136/2069858) it a bit, I found that I should also link it with the required library. However, in `igraph` folder I don't have any lib file. 
How can I link the project to the `igraph` library?

[image]

Comment: You need to add the include folder included with the project (pictured above) to the list of include paths for the project.  It's under "project properties", I think.

Comment: Thanks @1201ProgramAlarm This indeed helped. However, I got new errors due to unresolved reference. Please, see the edit.

Comment: Is the library in the `winlib` folder?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Unfortunately, it's empty. As winclude folder.