# C++ Failing to link the most basic application

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, unresolved-external

I was making a program for shader parsing and I wanted to move some pieces of code to different classes, then I got a lot of linker errors, started to debug them and tried to get to as basic situation as I can to eliminate them one by one, I removed all of the code and I don't know if it's just me being tired or there's something wrong with my visual studio but this code :

main.cpp

```
#include "Shader.h"

int main()
{
    Shader shader;
    shader.DoStuff();

    return 0;
}
```

Shader.h

```
#pragma once
class Shader
{
public:

    void DoStuff();
};
```

Shader.cpp

```
#include "Shader.h"
void Shader::DoStuff()
{
}
```

Generates linker error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall Shader::DoStuff(void)" (?DoStuff@Shader@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main   ShaderParser
```

Like, did I forget about something or what is going on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769977/lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-error-in-visual-studio-c

Comment: Please show your compile/link commandline.

Comment: I just have /VERBOSE added

Comment: @Werem "I just have /VERBOSE added" - that may be so, but could you *please* show us what the *actual*, *final* command line ends up as? How is the compiler/linker *actually* called in your case? I don't care what you did in some GUI, I want to see how the compiler actually ended up getting invoked, regardless of build-system etc. Just show us the actual commandline used.

Answer (score -1):

It has passed compilation and it can run correctly on my computer Visual Studio, no problems. So:

1. You had better check compilation options parameters.
2. Whether these 3 files are put in the correct paths(folders) as commands written.
3. "#pragma once" is not standard, try to change it to "#ifndef #define ... #endif"

The problem often happens when the pair of *.h and *.cpp are not corresponded.